# Subset of document-by-term matrix R

Tags: r

I am working in R and would like to retrieve a subset from my document-by-term matrix (dbtm), matching the row numbers in the dbtm to a second matrix with id numbers. All of the id numbers are row numbers in the dbtm. Some of the row numbers in dbtm are equal to my id variable. I read somewhere I have to apply data.frame to the latter and transpose.

I tried:

```
 subset(dbtm,subset=nrow(dbtm) %in% id)
```

I get all sorts of errors like `"$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"`, `"unexpected ','"` and `"object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"`.

Could anyone provide more insight? My guess is that i am not transforming/inputting my ids well. My apologies if this is very basic, I am busy on it since this morning with no result.

Many thanks,
Hanne

Comment: we can't answer this without knowing what is in `dbtm`, or how you created it. Can you give working reproducible example code?

Comment: Do you mean Document Term Matrix?